# What is wrong with my car?

Tags: engine, car, saturn

My car had a broken piston, and broke down completely. I bought a new engine, and had it installed. everything seemed to be working aside from a low clicking sound when driving coming from the engine. I was able to drive it great distances.

One day, as I was driving the radio just shut off for no reason. I had my friend who was driving accelerate to see if the car was still driving. The car moved fine. He pulled over anyway. Once he pulled over, he turned it off.

Since that day, it has not turned back on. I had the battery replaced, and that did nothing. Jumping it does nothing. It doesn't even make a clicking sound or try to turn over at all. Is it my alternator? Something worse?

I am having it towed to a mechanic soon, but before I waste the money to have them tell me it will cost more than the cars worth to fix, I thought I'd  ask around.

Answer (score 4):

If your car was running ok, then the alternator was at least providing charge. The fact you couldn't turn it on again after stopping suggests the battery was not holding any charge. So my initial guess would be battery (after eventually deciphering your question I realise you already tried replacing that)

I'd suggest you do also look at the alternator as well - especially with the ticking noise it may be that the alternator is on its last legs.

Aside from that, it's very tricky to diagnose over the Internet without more information, so my recommendation is still to get your mechanic to have a good look at it. Maybe it's just a dodgy connection somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I would take a guess at a faulty ignition switch.  The radio usually comes on with the ignition witch in position 1, but the ignition in position 2.  The radio stopped working, then after turning the switch, the ignition stopped working.